# Modify launch view when app is running in the background SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, rootview, uiscenedelegate

I understand that, in SwiftUI, the initial launch view is dependent on the Scene Delegate.
So, with something like this:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        //let contentView = ContentView() //only uncomment when messing with user db
        let contentView = FirstView()
       // let contentView = BarView(value: 3)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

I'm essentially telling Swift to open up the rootView of contentView, which is equal to FirstView() in this case. This gets run every time the app is opened, assuming that it was closed before (i.e. not running in the background)

However, if the app is running in the background (i.e. you just press the home button once on your iPad or whatever), and the users opens it again, the application will remember which view the user was last in, and resume that. Is there a way to change this behavior? Some way I can modify the Scene Delegate so that, when the app is running in the background and the user opens the application, the view will change to a specific view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update, nevermind, forgive the question. The solution is to put all your code inside this function in the Scene Delegate

```
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
        print("beans")
    }
```

this code will run when the app enters the foreground.

I'll leave the question up in case it helps anyone else!